# Different data dimension when indexing with R

Tags: r, training, validation

I am facing on something that I cannot explain, so may be someone could explain me. I have a dataset which contain 102011 data.

I want to take 70% for the train and 30% remaining for the validation. I wrote 2 differents code, but one gives me the good dimension of the trainset 70% of 102011 = 71407. and the second one gives me 71409. I cannot explain the 71409, that's not 70% of 102011.

here the code:

```
    train <- sample(nrow(dataset), 0.7*nrow(dataset), replace = FALSE)
TrainSet <- dataset[train,]
ValidSet <- dataset[-train,]
dim(dataset)
71407 8
```

and there, the one which gives as output 71409:

```
validation_index <- createDataPartition(dataset$RENDU, p=0.70, list=FALSE)
# select 30% of the data for validation
validation <- dataset[-validation_index,]
# use the remaining 70% of data to training and testing the models
dataset <- dataset[validation_index,]
dim(dataset)
[1] 71409     8
```

Does anyone can explain me why this difference?
Thanks.